# How can I apply shell command on the selected files in netrw

Tags: netrw

I want to apply a shell command on two selected files, my command is:

```
convert +append image1.png image2.png output.png
```

How can I do that for two selected images in netrw?
However, to make the process easier I wrote a shell function named `append` which takes two image and generates and output name for them and applies `convert` on them. Now, how can I use my shell function on the selected files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Mark the files using one of ways detailed [here](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-mf). (E.g. type `mf` with the cursor over a filename.)
2. Type `mx`
3. At the prompt enter your shell command.

   - If you want to specify where marked files should be inserted in the command line indicate this with a `%`.
   - Alternatively, don't add a `%` and marked files will follow the command after a space.
4. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The command should then be run on each file in turn.

The example found in the relevant section of [netrw docs](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-mx)

```
(mark files)
mx
Enter command: cat
```

The result is a series of shell commands:

```
cat 'file1'
cat 'file2'
...
```

---

If instead you want the command *run once on all the files at one time* use `mX` instead of `mx`.

The [documentation](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-mX) example for that one, showing creation of a tarball:

```
(mark files)
mX
Enter command: tar cf mynewtarball.tar
```

The command that will be run with this example:

```
tar cf mynewtarball.tar 'file1' 'file2' ...
```

Comment: Thanks, how about applying a shell function I defined myself?

Comment: Can I create aliases for some comnads like `convert +append % out.png`

Comment: You'll either need to make sure your PATH includes your script before you start Vim or you should specify it's full path at the prompt that follows `mx`/`mX`. (I haven't tried this but I'm pretty confident it'll work. Let me know if you have issues.)

Comment: Thank you, yes, a shell script in current directory can be called.

Comment: If I could map the process to a key, it was even easier: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31627/can-i-map-a-netrw-command-and-its-arguments-to-a-key

Comment: what about the current directory, it doesn't seem markeable?

Comment: @CervEd It works for me. For example, I put the cursor on "./", do `mf`, then `mx`, type `ls` then `Enter` and it shows the listing for that directory.

Comment: @BLayer yes that seems to work, perhaps I do something occasionally do something wonky that unmarks it