# Can I map a netrw command and its arguments to a key?

Tags: key-bindings, netrw

I have this map:

```
nmap <buffer> <F3> mX
```

So one I press `<F3>` it opens a prompt so I can type a command. Can I give the command also in the map above? something like:

```
nmap <buffer> <F3> mX  ./app
```

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you, but no

Comment: I don't think either mapping or `feedkeys()` will work because `s:NetrwMarkFileExe` uses `inputsave()`/`inputrestore()`